# Is the following enough to protect my secret key and database password for heroku deployment?

Tags: django, heroku

I have added the environment variables through to get secret key database name and password. Now anything else to make it more secure.Let me know.

Used "Advance system settings" and under that added environment variables in "User variables" .
Also this is going to be my first deployment on 'heroku' that's why following a tutorial.

```
SECRET_KEY = os.environ['DB_SECRET']
```

databases

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'portfoliodb',
        'USER': os.environ.get('DB_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('DB_PASS'),
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

Comment: That depends, what are you protecting them from?

Comment: Just a sample portfolio nothing big. But if need improvement plz let me know

Comment: Your question is too broad, you could go into key rotation, or user access rights to environment variables in heroku amongst other things.

Comment: `os.environ.get['DB_USER']` ?? its `.get('DB_USER')` anyone correct me if i am wrong. use parentheses

Comment: @Sayse no problem . just tell me the way to deploy website on heroku without displaying this information on Git and heroku.

Comment: @Moha369 you are right. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Heroku has a package that handles that for you. More info [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-app-configuration). Essentially, it overrides default with secure credentials automatically generated in the Heroku platform.

> Add the following import statement to the top of settings.py:
>
> `import django_heroku`
>
> Then add the following to the bottom of settings.py:
>
> Activate Django-Heroku.
>
> `django_heroku.settings(locals())`

Comment: Thanks. As i have to push it to Git first will it take care of that also? Otherwise this information will be visible on git

Comment: Yep, it should. Also you should write either os.environ['DB_PASS'] or os.environ.get('DB_PASS')

Comment: I have added import django_heroku and changed parantheses as well. Now will it be fine to git push and deploy to heroku?

Comment: Yep. Heroku will give you feedback if it's not